# Add `'` in a query in crystal reports

Tags: sql, crystal-reports

I am building a crystal reports query and  I want to add `'` in a Query, how can I do that?

```
WHERE "Table"."Id" = {?ParamID}
```

i want to surround `{?ParamID}` with `'`.

Comment: try using in passing parameters in sqlcommand parameter

Comment: It's ambiguous as to what problem you're trying to solve here. This is from a SQL Command? Is `{?ParamID}` a string parameter? What's your actual issue?